# Make a column full width in an inner section

Tags: columns, content-width

What I want to achieve is to make a template element of a column and its content. Since I cannot make a global template of a column I have put it into an inner section, and made the inner section the global template.

My issue is that the column has a margin within the inner section:

[image: Green column within yellow inner section]

I assume there is a setting for making the column fill the entire horizontal space, but cannot find it. Also there seem to be no results for this on google, but I would assume it to be a common feature, so I feel that I have missed a basic setting...

Is it possible to make a column fill the entire inner section?

Comment: Your screenshot doesn’t look like the block editor. Are you using a page builder plugin of some kind?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Elementor pro

Comment: This is a question you'll need to direct to its author/community. 3rd party plugins are off topic here.